# Revert from dark nimbus theme to default in netbeans

Tags: themes, uninstall, plugins, netbeans

I installed the Dark Nimbus theme in netbeans' plugin manager. Now theme has changed but I do not like it. I uninstalled it from plugin manager. but nothing happened. What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isn't Dark Nimbus theme, it appears as if you have `ez-on-da-ice` (Another dark LAF plugin) installed. Uninstall it and then make sure you have removed the `--laf javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel` removed from the netbeans.conf file. You should then be able to see default LAF for linux. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Plugins > Installed > Dark Nimbus Theme > Uninstall :)